# I can not show value of array from a database( mongodb) with widget ListView in Flutter

Tags: arrays, flutter, dart, listview

i have a data
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocaiv.png)

i want to show information this data with widget ListView in Flutter, but its error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gx5kJ.png)

my code List View
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ji6ix.png)

i check this data in console, its oke
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6tzU.png)

How i can fix it??????????

Comment: At where you print the data in console? Add it in your code as well.

Comment: Also, how you define `data`?

Comment: I print the data in console before i put code list view

Comment: And i get data from my database

Comment: can you paste the full error?

Answer (score 0):

You actually used some bank operator somewhere ("!"), provide please all of your code, so we could help more efficenty.

Comment: Thanhk Timur, answer my question

Comment: It error in default code in flutter, i dont know  how to fix it, i think if i edit default code in flutter, it can make error other my code

Comment: provide full screenshot of your screen where you want to show data in listView so i could help you fix it. :)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).